# Change part of link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, sorting

I am using Ransack for sorting. I couldn't find way to change sorting links when search and sorting uses just ajax. So I am developing my own solution to change link and some other stuff.

So far I have this

**Ruby**

```
<%= search_form_for @search, :class=>"search",:id=>"search-menio",:remote=>"true", url: advertisements_path, :method => :get do |f| %>
    <div class="sort-link-css"> 
       <%= sort_link(@search, :price,"CENA", {},{ :remote => true, :method => :get }) %>
   </div>
<%end%>
```

**that generates this :**

```
<div class="sort-link-css">                                     
    <a class="sort_link asc" data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/lv/advertisements?q%5Bs%5D=price+desc">CENA&nbsp;▲</a>                                             
</div>
```

**My goal:**

When user clicks on this link it will change link class that represents sorting order and end of the link that also represents sorting order.

```
 asc -> desc
 desc -> asc
```

And then it submits search form.

**Problem:**
For first click I see some blinking and changes, but when I try second click nothing happens.

**My script:**

```
$('.sort-link-css > a').click(function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    if (className = "sort link asc") {
        $(this).removeClass('sort link asc');
        this.href = this.href.replace('desc', 'asc');
        $(this).attr('class', 'sort link desc');
    } else if (className = "sort link desc") {
        $(this).removeClass('sort link desc');
        this.href = this.href.replace('asc', 'desc');
        $(this).attr('class', 'sort link asc');
    }
    $('.search').submit();
})
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: For a start: You are reassiging `className` in your if statement. `className = "sort link asc"` is just assiging a string to className. You should use `==` for testing or even better `===`.

Comment: @Mikey Thanks, but now if statement doesn't work anymore with both '==' and '===' when comparing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would use [`jQuery.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) or [`jQuery.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to determine if an element has the specified class or classes.

You also need to update the display before navigation or form submit. You can do all this:

```
$('.sort-link-css > a').click(function(e) {
    // cancel the click  event on the link
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is('.asc')) {
        this.href = this.href.replace('desc', 'asc');
    } else if ($this.is('.desc')) {
        this.href = this.href.replace('asc', 'desc');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('asc desc');
    setTimeout(function() {
        // I am not sure if you want to load the link href
        // or submit the form; use one of the following
        window.location = $this.get(0).href;
        $('.search').submit();
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thank You, I would like to ask. Maybe you now how I can change sorting order indicator without adding my own images, but using originals? At this point class changes but those indicators not..

Comment: I _think_ this is because the browser starts navigating to the other page and therefore does not update the page display. See revised answer in a minute.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but still those sorting direction bullets not changing.

Comment: You mean on the next page that opens?

Comment: No, I mean in the same page.

Comment: I am not sure. Make sure you have the ` e.preventDefault();` line placed in the beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80485/discussion-between-salman-a-and-edgars-rozenfelds).

Answer (score 1):

Please try using hasClass().

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
$(this).hasClass( "sort link asc" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are quite a few mistakes in your jQuery. You `class="sort_link asc"` are in fact two classes and not three. I have made a fiddle, just try to understand it and you will see where you are going wrong: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vdkt3cd8/2/)

```
$('.sort-link-css > a').click(function () {

    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(className);

    if (className == "sort_link asc") {
        $(this).removeClass('sort_link asc');
        alert("removed class sort_link asc");

    } else if (className == "sort_link desc") {

        $(this).removeClass('sort link desc');
        this.href = this.href.replace('asc', 'desc');
        $(this).attr('class', 'sort link asc');

    }

    else {
     alert("all tests failed");   
    }

})
```